# Bigquery API limit exceeded error while doing the preview

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

When I am trying to do preview a table in bigquery having size 500mb and no of rows less than 10000,It is throwing an error:

API limit exceeded.Message before conversion exceeds max row limit 10978654 Actual 44386547.

Even if it's a very small table ,I am getting this error.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is complaining about a single row size exceeds 10MB (yours is 43 MB). It has nothing to do with how many rows you have in your table.

Comment: Thanks Yun for your quick response. As per the documentation max size of a row is 100mb.Correct me if I am wrong.
 Here in this case data is already  in the table and I am trying to preview it. I am not inserting in the table. 

 In the documentation I could see Maximum response size: 10 MB . Am I facing the issue because of the above response size limit ?

Comment: I think so. Normally, the API trim the output number of rows to limit response size to 10MB, but when single row is too large, it reports an error.